# RoR: Select All

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, find

I am using Ruby On Rails, and I can't figure out how to retrieve all records.  The table in question is expected to only have 52 records, so I'm not worried about performance in this particular instance.  I have tried Model.all, but that just gives me an Active_Record relation, when what I really need is an Array of models. I have also looked at using the find method, but Intellij says that it is deprecated.

Any help with this embarrassing question is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does the table and associations look like?

Comment: `Model.all` should work. There is something wrong in your setup.

Comment: Give us info about your associations - this will likely be the reason you're getting a `relation` object back. If you detail your model, we'll be able to provide more in depth information about how to set up your associations correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the relation to an array by doing `Model.all.to_a`

Answer (score 3):

> Model.all.to_a

in Rails 4

> Modal.all

in Rails 3.

BOTH are same

Model.all from "Rails 3", you can call to_a on the returned ActiveRecordRelation

Answer (score 1):

```
Model.all
```

is enough to retrieve all records from corresponding table, check your model class, table and database connection.

Answer (score 0):

Fin all model of app by using :

```
 ActiveRecord::Base.subclasses.collect { |type| type.name }
```